# java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to when implementing parcelable

Tags: java, android, classcastexception

I am running out of ideas as to why my implementation of parcelable does throw ClassCastException. I would like to know why it does throw the exception and find ways on how to fix it.Please let me know if I'm still lacking to give information in order for you guys to help me.

IdModelDTO class

```
public class IdModelDTO implements Parcelable {
private String type;
private String surname;
private String givenName;
private String middleName;
private String birthDate;

protected IdModelDTO(Parcel in) {
    givenName = in.readString();
    middleName = in.readString();
    surname = in.readString();
    birthDate = in.readString();
    type = in.readString();
} 
public static final Creator<IdModelDTO> CREATOR = new Creator<IdModelDTO(){
    @Override
    public IdModelDTO createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new IdModelDTO(in);
    }

    @Override
    public IdModelDTO[] newArray(int size) {
        return new IdModelDTO[size];
    }
};

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeString(givenName);
    dest.writeString(middleName);
    dest.writeString(surname);
    dest.writeString(birthDate);
    dest.writeString(type);
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "IdModelDTO{" + "givenName='" + givenName + '\''
            + ", middleName='" + middleName + '\'' +
            "surname='" + surname + '\'' +
            "birthdate=''" + birthDate + '\'' +
            "type='" + type +  '\'' + '}';
}
```

This is where I use it as a bundle. I can even log it as a bundle before sending it to the next activity:

```
public void checkMplusRespCodes() {
        // Check if response codes are OK/Created:
        if(governmentIdRespCode == null){
            Log.d(TAG, "Government Id Response code: " + governmentIdRespCode );
        }
        if(saveSelfieResponse == null){
            Log.d(TAG, "saveSelfieResponse: " + saveSelfieResponse);
        }
        else if(governmentIdRespCode != null && saveSelfieResponse != null){
            if(governmentIdRespCode.equals("200") && saveSelfieResponse.equals("200")){
                //Create bundle here, then pass it to view:
                //Bundle idModelBundle = new Bundle();
                //idModelBundle.putParcelable(THISIDMODEL, thisIdModel);
                //viewContract.showNextActivity(idModelBundle);
                Log.d(TAG, " checkMplusRespCodes: " + idModelDTO.toString());
                Bundle idModelBundle = new Bundle();
                idModelBundle.putParcelable(THISIDMODEL, idModelDTO);
                viewContract.showDoneLoading();
                viewContract.showNextActivity(idModelBundle);
            }
        }
```

Then at the nextactivity, it throws the ClassCastException:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_test1);
    /* */
    Intent previousIntent = getIntent();
    if(previousIntent.getExtras() != null){
        Bundle previousExtras = previousIntent.getExtras();
        if(previousExtras != null){
            IdModelDTO test = previousIntent.getParcelableExtra(THISIDMODEL);
            if(test != null){
                Log.d(TAG, " asd: " + test.toString());
            }
            /* Retrieve: */
        }
    }else{
        //proceed.
    }
```

Any kind of help will be much appreciated.

**EDIT:**
This is the log of the method whereas I set the Parcelable object as a bundle:

```
checkMplusRespCodes: IdModelDTO{givenName='test', middleName='asd'surname='Test'birthdate=''axx'type='asxd'}
```

The exception occurs at the nextActivity where it's being casted:

```
IdModelDTO test = previousIntent.getParcelableExtra(THISIDMODEL);
```

Comment: What is the output of
`Log.d(TAG, " checkMplusRespCodes: " + idModelDTO.toString());`
And in which line exactly the ClassCastException occurs in your last code snippet?

Comment: I updated my question, it occurs at the next activity when it's inside the bundle, being being casted as another object of the same type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I solved this. I was passing casting a Bundle Object into my custom IdModelDTO as you can see in this line:

```
if(previousExtras != null){
        IdModelDTO test = previousIntent.getParcelableExtra(THISIDMODEL);
        ...
```

I removed the Bundle part where I put my object inside the bundle, and use the putExtra in order for me to be able to retrieve the object as it's type:

```
Intent nextActivityIntent = new Intent(this, TestActivityX.class);
nextActivityIntent.putExtra(THISIDMODEL,idModelDTO);
Log.d(TAG, " Show next activity: " + idModelDTO.toString());
startActivity(nextActivityIntent);
```

Then the retrieval will work on the next activity:

```
Intent previousIntent = getIntent();
    if (previousIntent.getExtras() != null) {
        Bundle previousExtras = previousIntent.getExtras();
        if (previousExtras != null) {
            // Retrieve:
            if (previousExtras.containsKey(THISIDMODEL)) {
                // Re-instanciate new user.
                IdModelDTO test = previousExtras.getParcelable(THISIDMODEL);
                Log.d(TAG, " Previous Details:" + test.toString());
            }
        }
    }
```

Thanks guys, I really appreciate the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code with this

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_test1);
    /* */
    Intent previousIntent = getIntent();
    if(previousIntent.getExtras() != null){
        Bundle previousExtras = previousIntent.getExtras();
        if(previousExtras != null){
            IdModelDTO test = previousExtras.getParcelable(THISIDMODEL);
            if(test != null){
                Log.d(TAG, " asd: " + test.toString());
            }
            /* Retrieve: */
        }
    }else{
        //proceed.
    }
```

Comment: try this way IdModelDTO test = (IdModelDTO)previousExtras.getParcelable(THISIDMODEL);

Comment: I already tried it before. The IDE says that it's unnecessary but I tried it still, and returned the same response. I think it was how I structured my Parcelable object.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to parse `date` object which is not a `String`.

That is why you are getting this exception.

Comment: No, the birthdate was already a String value before getting instanciated inside a new IdModelDTO. But good observation, sir.